# Okteto ignore certain yaml file

Tags: github, kubernetes-deployment, okteto

In my GitHub repo I have 2 yaml files:

- `k8s/deploy-all-secrets.yaml`
- `k8s/deploy-edge.yaml`

I make use of cloud.okteto.com to deploy this deployment-file. But I don't want Okteto to deploy the `deploy-all-secrets.yaml` file. Is there any way I can exclude this file from Okteto?

I tried using a `.stignore` file, but this had no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation https://okteto.com/docs/cloud/okteto-pipeline/.
You can place any k8s manifest file that needs to be executed using `kubectl apply` in this folder. So by simply removing the `deploy-all-secrets.yaml` from the `k8s` folder, it won't be executed by Okteto.

Answer (score 4):

Another option you have is to create an `okteto-pipeline.yaml` file at the root of your repo. This allows you to control how Okteto deploys your pipeline. For the scenario you describe, it would look like this:

```
deploy:
- kubectl apply -f deploy-all-secrets.yaml
```

More information on how to customize your pipelie [is available here](https://okteto.com/docs/cloud/okteto-pipeline/#customize-the-okteto-pipeline).

Note: The `.stignore` file is only used by the `okteto up` command, during the file synchronization phase. More information on that [is available here](https://okteto.com/docs/reference/file-synchronization/#ignoring-files).